# Horizontal UL list is not showing LI items in same line

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've been trying to get UL to show LI items horizontally by doing "float:left".

```
float:left;
display:inline;
```

Here is example - http://jsfiddle.net/Ku9Bm/1/

As you can see it shows LI items line up horizontally perfectly.

But if I add more text to one of the LI item UL list shows LI items vertically.

Here is example of that - http://jsfiddle.net/3DGfL/2/

How can I show LI items in same line even if one LI item has more content?

Comment: remove `float:left;`, `display:inline;` takes care of showing the list items horizontally.

Comment: There's enough content in your second element to take up the entire width of the parent element, what were you expecting?  Float is not a "make these elements appear side by side no matter what" property

Comment: In cases like this prefer `inline-block` over `inline` usually.

Comment: Are you saying that if the window isn't wide enough that the text drops down to the next line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to get the behaviour (that I think) you're looking for may be to use a different display property. You could try this styling to replace your current one defined for `ul.entries li`:

```
ul.entries li {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

If you want the list items to be wider to reduce automatic line breaking, you can also add a `min-width` there as well. Now, your horizontal list items will stay on the same line regardless of width, and won't wrap with previous list items if their content requires they break to additional lines.

I hope this helps you out! Good luck. (Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DGfL/4/), just in case you want to see it in action.)